# Ebay scraper makes a dataframe but can´t use the numbers for future graphics

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrape

I´m trying to make an easy scraper with python for ebay, the thing is I can´t use the dataframe I make.
My code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from csv import reader

url = "https://www.ebay.es/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=iphone&_sacat=0&LH_TitleDesc=0&_fsrp=1&Modelo=Apple%2520iPhone%2520X&_dcat=9355"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

productslist = []
results = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 's-item__info clearfix'})
print(len(results))
for item in results:
    product = {
        'title': item.find('h3', {'class': 's-item__title'}),
        'soldprice': item.find('span', {'class': 's-item__price'})
    }
        
    productslist.append(product)

df =  pd.DataFrame(productslist)
df
```

But the dataframe I get it´s like this:
[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpjaW.jpg)

I would like to be able to work with the numbers of the price but I can´t use it, I imagine it´s because dtype: object, I would like to know how to convert for example [359,00 EUR] in 359,00 to be able to make graphics.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the "price" from a `[...]` format, use the `.text` method. Also, make sure that the price not `None`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


url = "https://www.ebay.es/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=iphone&_sacat=0&LH_TitleDesc=0&_fsrp=1&Modelo=Apple%2520iPhone%2520X&_dcat=9355"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
productslist = []
results = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "s-item__info clearfix"})

for item in results:
    title = item.find("h3", {"class": "s-item__title"})
    price = item.find("span", {"class": "s-item__price"})
    if price is None:
        continue
    productslist.append({"title": title.text, "soldprice": price.text})


df = pd.DataFrame(productslist)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                               title                soldprice
0   APPLE IPHONE X 64 GB A+LIBRE+FACTURA+8 ACCESOR...               359,00 EUR
1               Apple iPhone X - 64GB - Plata (Libre)               177,50 EUR
2             Apple iPhone X - 64GB - Blanco  (Libre)               181,50 EUR
3                                       iphone x 64gb               240,50 EUR
4                                     Iphone x 256 gb               370,00 EUR
5         Apple iPhone X - 256GB - Space Gray (Libre)               400,00 EUR
6   Nuevo anuncioSMARTPHONE APPLE IPHONE X 64GB LI...               334,95 EUR
...
...
```